# Tuning RubyMine IDE

Tags: rubymine

This happens for every single project that I have tried:
If I use terminal and say bundle install or rake db:migrate , it works fine, can see my website , works completely fine.

But If I open project in RubyMine and want to do the same tasks it gives me all sorts or errors. I  just copy paster some of them as an example.

I am sure there is some small project setting that should be set somewhere. But don't know what and where

Note: There is a "edit configuration" that is always set on Rails 1.8 and although I change it to Rails 1.9 , still makes no difference.

I am running the latest version of RubyMine on Mac.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /usr/bin/rake db:migrate
/Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in `materialize': Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `map!'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:83:in `materialize'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:113:in `specs'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:158:in `specs_for'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
```

**EDIT:  After running bundler install, from IDE :**

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Users/JonyIve/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Gem::Exception: Cannot load gem at [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/rake-10.0.3.gem] in /Users/JonyIve/Downloads/code-1/rails32/depot_c
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked from the author, here is his answer:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5476810#5476810

Comment: In case the link goes away, his tip was to make sure you have the correct SDK selected in `Preferences | Ruby SDK` and Gems.

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error while using RubyMine. I have solved the "no tty present...." error by adding:

```
Defaults    visiblepw
```

to

```
/etc/sudoers
```

file.

Comment: 'sudo visudo' to edit the file for those new to this type of issue

Comment: This is still the case with rubymine 7/Mac OS Yosemite, thanks @Uygar and @plosco!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Tools->Run Bundler from the IDE menu? You need to run the Bundler from within Rubymine in addition to the console to update the IDE's copy of the gems.

Comment: yes. 
But you mean running it two times? first from console and then from IDE?

Comment: yes it uses a java ruby version and is scoped to be within rubyMine.

Comment: ok did it now, it gave new errors. It is just easier to update the post with the new error. It is hard to read them here in the comments section.

Comment: Did you try running 'gem install rake'

Comment: yes, both from IDE and Terminal...in Terminal it said one gem installed, in IDE did not show any feedback....then again from IDE I did a Bundle Install and again showed me the same error.

Comment: Do you have gem 'rake' in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

okay, i had this same issue.  it was caused because the ruby that rubymine sdk was pointing to was the system ruby,  /usr/bin/ruby--- aliased to the one in Library instead of the one in ln -svf /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby

replacing the link with the one pointing to the local version solved the issue.