# Rails server not working in Rubymine but working in terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with `rvm env`:

```
export PATH ; PATH="/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-    1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-    p392/bin:/home/wojtek/.rvm/bin:$PATH"
export rvm_env_string ; rvm_env_string='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export rvm_path ; rvm_path='/home/wojtek/.rvm'
export rvm_ruby_string ; rvm_ruby_string='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
unset rvm_gemset_name
export RUBY_VERSION ; RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export GEM_HOME ; GEM_HOME='/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export GEM_PATH ; GEM_PATH='/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-    p392:/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME ; MY_RUBY_HOME='/home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export IRBRC ; IRBRC='/home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
```

When try to start the app in RubyMine 5.0.2 I get:

```
/home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby     /home/wojtek/workspace/quotes/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run the same command line in a terminal it works fine:

```
/home/wojtek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby /home/wojtek/workspace/quotes/script/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431111/tuning-rubymine-ide

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to `Settings -> Ruby SDK and gems` and select `Ruby1.9.3_orsomething_[global]` (the `[global]` is the important part) in `Ruby SDK`.
2. Run `Tools -> Bundler -> Install`.

Dont know why, but it worked.